# Element type is invalid: expected string (for built in components) issue with React-navigation's TabBartIcon

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, expo

[image]

When We want to include Ionicons inside the tab navigator in react-navigation it shows this error which looks like very strange, as far as we are using the guide of react-navigation how to implement it. Here is the code:

```
import { Ionicons } from "react-native-vector-icons";
..............
.............
..............
const TabsBar = TabNavigator(
  {

   Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
   Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},

  },

    {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = 'search';
        } 
         else if (routeName === 'Profile') {
          iconName = 'contact';
        }

        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#222222',
      inactiveTintColor: '#222222',
    },
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    initialRouteName: 'Home'

  }
);
```

We are using react-navigation version: 1.0.0-beta.21

What is wrong in this code and how can we fix this issue?

Comment: Is your iconName is undefined ? Did you checked ?

Answer (score 1):

You have imported it wrongly. Change your import as below `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
const TabsBar = TabNavigator(
  {

   Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
   Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},

  },

      {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = `ios-information-circle${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        } else if (routeName === 'Profile') {
          iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here! We usually use an
        // icon component from react-native-vector-icons
        return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
       activeTintColor: '#222222',
      inactiveTintColor: '#222222',
    },
     tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);
```